# How to make navbar links appear vertically below the navbar when hamburger icon is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Im just beginning my web design journey and I have created this nice little responsive navbar using flexbox. When the screen width is less than 600px, all links disappear and the hamburger icon appears correctly where it should.

However, I am now pretty stumped on how to make the navigation menu appear when the hamburger icon is clicked. I want the links to appear vertically below the menu in an appealing way like on most websites. Please help me to understand how I would do this.

I have included my HTML and CSS for the Navbar below...

```css
body
{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.column-layout
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: grey;
}

.brand-logo
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#navbar-logo
{
    height: 90px;
}

.nav-links
{
  flex: 1;
}

.nav-links ul
{
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.nav-links ul li
{
  padding: 25px;
}

.nav-links li a 
{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.social-links
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.social-icon
{
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.hamburger
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.hamburger_icon
{
    display: none;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

/* Media Queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) 
{
    .nav-links
    {
        display: none;
    }

    .social-links
    {
        display: none;
    }

    .hamburger_icon 
    {
        display: initial;
    }

    .brand-logo
    {
        margin:0;
    }

    #navbar-logo
    {
        height: 80px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!-- NAVBAR -->
    <nav>
        <div class="column-layout">
            <div class="brand-logo">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg" id="navbar-logo">
            </div>
            <div class="nav-links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Packages</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="social-links">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook-square social-icon"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-instagram social-icon"></i>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hamburger_icon" onclick="myFunction()">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="hamburger">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hamburger_icon" onclick="myFunction()">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: This is a great little example, many thanks for your code! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use any framework like bootstrap. It will save your time. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/                     https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp 
If you dont want to use bootstrap then u will have to write media query

Comment: Yeah I would want to write the media query myself. What would this entail?